# Non parallel, linear independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have came across a problem in my notes that I am looking for some help with. Let

$$ \text{vector 1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1   
\\2
\\3
\\4
\end{bmatrix} \qquad\qquad \text{vector 2} =  \begin{bmatrix}
1
\\4
\\6
\\8
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am using these vectors combined with the standard basis vectors to form a basic in $\mathbb R^4$. So I understand that they need to have a $rank=4$ and they must be linearly independent. In my notes it says that these two vectors above are non-parallel and they are linearly independent. Just looking to clarify why this is non parallel and linearly independent. I understand the rest, just not these two terms. Are these columns independent because they have non trivial parts?

Comment: @ null thanks for the edit

Comment: multiple scaler meaning that you cant multiply v1 by anything to give you the components of v2 and the same for v2?

Comment: Yes...by anything *in the field* $\;\Bbb R\;$ , over which $\;\Bbb R^4\;$ is defined .

Comment: what is in the field of R4?

Comment: @J Read again...and *always* wait two minutes before you answer. In that time corrections of typos and etc. are done.

Comment: okay thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the definition of linear independence to two vectors $v$ and $w$.

> Two vectors $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent if for any scalars $a$ and $b$, the condition $av+bw=0$ implies $a=b=0$.

Also, since you seem to be confused about the definition of parallel,

> Two vectors $v$ and $w$ are parallel if there exists a scalar $c$ such that $v=cw$.

Now, if $v=cw$ (i.e. $v$ and $w$ are parallel), then we have $v-cw=0$. This implies $v$ and $w$ are not linearly independent. The converse follows a similar argument. So in the case of two vectors, *linear independence is the same as being non-parallel.*

---

For your example, it is easy to see that the first vector is not a multiple of the other, so they are non-parallel and linearly independent.

Comment: got it, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Parallel and linearly **dependent** is one and the same in this (euclidean) case: none of $\;v_1,\,v_2\;$ is a multiple scalar of the other one. Because of this they are non-parallel = they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot write $v_1$ as a linear combination(scaling) of the other: There is no $\lambda$ to satisfy $v_1=\lambda v_2$. If you have other vectors, you shouldn't be able to find $\mathbf{\lambda}=\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3\}$ s.t.:
$$
v_1 = \lambda_1 v_2 + \lambda_2 v_3 + \lambda_3 v_4
$$

This is easy to show. Two (hyper-)planes will be parallel if one of the vectors (i.e. the plane parameters) can be written as a scaling of the other:
$$
\lambda v_1 = v_2
$$